# Trying to make TextField first responder before dismiss

Tags: swift, drop-down-menu, uitextfield

I am using a dropdown menu library called [DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown). I want to include a Search Text Field above that view. I can create it when user selects and the dropdown is presented. But when the `UITextField` is being clicked , The dropDown is being dismissed. I want to make the `UITextField` dismissed when someone taps outside of the view , but not the UITextField. I can make `dropdown.dismissMode = .Manual` and handle the dismiss myself.

now I have (but the UITextField is also dismissed when I tap on it)

```
dropDown.cancelAction = { [unowned self] in
self.textFiled.removeFromSuperView()
}
```